# Laravel calling controller function from blade file not working

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project where I'm trying to call a controller function from blade file called `nav.blade.php`, but I'm getting following error:

> syntax error, unexpected fully qualified name
> "\App\Http\Controllers\ProductC...", expecting ":".

**nav.blade.php**

```
{{ use \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController; }}

<div class="container">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         {{ $is_admin = ProductController::isAdmin(); }}

                @if($is_admin == "admin")
                      <li class="nav-item">
                           <a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Admin</a>
                      </li>
                @endif   
  </ul>
</div>
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
 public static function isAdmin()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::id();
        $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
     
        $is_admin = $user->role;
        if($is_admin==="admin"){
            return "admin";
        }elseif($is_admin==="moderator"){
            return "moderator";
        }else{
            return "user";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried`{{dd($is_admin)}}` to check what it actually contains? Also, why not make this a method/attribute in the User model? `Auth::user()` will give you the currently auth'd user

Answer (score 0):

`{{ }}` are used to `echo` anything you want. If you want to import a class, one solution is to do like the following:

```
<?php
    use \App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;  
    $is_admin = ProductController::isAdmin();
?>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        @if($is_admin == "admin")
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Admin</a>
            </li>
        @endif   
    </ul>
</div>
```

But this isn't a best practice I recommend you to move `isAdmin()` method from `ProductController` and set it as global function of your system so you can directly access it from your view without importing a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Never EVER use a controller in a Blade. That is not good in any way and would require me a lot of explanation that is already in some blogs...

A controller is ONLY used for accessing something through a URL, do something and done, it is not a `Service` class where you do business logic anywhere you want.

So, move that method to a `Service` class (do not confuse with `Service Provider`) and use it in the blade. It would still be better to pass that variable to the view and not using any class just for that...

Answer (score 0):

You access the static controller function from the blade template.

```
<?php 
$isAdmin= App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::isAdmin();
?>
```